# isNullOrEmpty function in spark to check column in data frame is null or empty string

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, bigdata

How can I check the columns of dataframe is null or empty ins spark.

Ex.

```
type IdentifiedDataFrame = {SourceIdentfier, DataFrame}
def splitRequestIntoDFsWithAndWithoutTransactionId(df: DataFrame) : Seq[IdentifiedDataFrame] = {
  seq((DeltaTableStream(RequestWithTransactionId), df.filter(col(RequestLocationCodeColName).isNull
      && col(ServiceNumberColName).isNull
      && col(DateOfServiceColName).isNull
      && col(TransactionIdColName).isNotNull)).
    
      (DeltaTableStream(RequestWithoutTransactionId), df.filter(col(RequestLocationCodeColName).isNotNull
       && col(ServiceNumberColName).isNotNull
       && col(DateOfServiceColName).isNotNull))
      )
}
```

Note : this code only check the null value in column  and I want to check null or empty string both
Please help

Answer (score 1):

You can use `isNull` function and check for empty String with `filter` as below

```
val columns = List("column1", "column2")

val filter = columns.map(c => isnull(col(c)) || !(col(c) <=> lit("")))
  .reduce(_ and _)

df.filter(filter)
```

Comment: Hi Koirala, i paseted the main code where is am using isNull but now i have to make function and use isNullOrEmpty instead of isNull can you please help in this

Comment: But this was not your original question, and title doesnot match the contents

Comment: Ohh can u pls help me in this

Comment: In place of isNull i want to use isNullOrEmpty and inplace of isNotNull I want use isNotNullOrEmpty

Comment: I am new in development  and I need to do this. It will very helpful if u help me out

Comment: The question is not just clear to me , take a look here if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60213412/spark-scala-check-if-string-isnt-null-or-empty

Comment: Thank you,  same thing I also want to do. But the link provided by you giving me type mismatch error

Comment: I just want to make a function similar to isNull but it should also check empty string with null value.