# how to filter isNullOrEmpty in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

In code below, I am filtering based on isNull and now I want to filter null or Empty string both. Can anyone please help me with this code:

```
type IdentifiedDataFrame = {SourceIdentfier, DataFrame}
def splitRequestIntoDFsWithAndWithoutTransactionId(df: DataFrame) : Seq[IdentifiedDataFrame] = {
    seq((DeltaTableStream(RequestWithTransactionId), 
         df.filter(
           col(RequestLocationCodeColName).isNull &&
           col(ServiceNumberColName).isNull &&
           col(DateOfServiceColName).isNull &&
           col(TransactionIdColName).isNotNull)),
        
        (DeltaTableStream(RequestWithoutTransactionId),
         df.filter(
           col(RequestLocationCodeColName).isNotNull &&
           col(ServiceNumberColName).isNotNull &&
           col(DateOfServiceColName).isNotNull)))
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [isNullOrEmpty function in spark to check column in data frame is null or empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68298944/isnullorempty-function-in-spark-to-check-column-in-data-frame-is-null-or-empty-s)